# How to reformat a single RAID 5 disk for normal use?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-5

I have a few RAID 5 disks from a computer that broke and I’m wondering, I have them all plugged in but how do I reformat them for normal use? My Linux machine doesn’t even pick up the devices. Just a few gigs of TMPFS.

Comment: How do you know your computer doesn't pick them up? You shouldn't expect the Raid5 to automagically assemble on your system, it doesn't work like that. They will likely show up as raid members, but won't be readable at all.

Comment: How did you determine it doesn’t see the devices? Please provide the output of `fdisk -l`.

Comment: As @Tonny said, the key is that it needs more than just formatting, it needs re-partitioning. In a raid 5 the partition table would also have been spread across all three disks... thus Linux can't identify the partitions. This would cause, for example, `/dev/sdb` to appear, but not `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`, etc. One can also use [blkid](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) as root to see what block devices are detected, if it doesn't show up there you have more serious problems.

Answer (score 2):

The disks should show as devices in your system but they most likely don't have any valid partition table on it.

This makes them unavailable for automatically mounting/showing them on your desktop.

Use `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `gparted` or any other partitioning tool of your choice.

It should show the disks as either raid-member or as unformatted.

Simply give it a fresh partition table (either MBR or GPT, depending on your system and BIOS, when in doubt use the same type as the disk your /-filesystem is on) and then you can proceed as usual creating partitions.